# open html select in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I would like to know if there is an event in Firefox that opens an html select.

In Chrome 'mousedown' works, but in Firefox it doesn't.

My code is something like

```
event = new MouseEvent('mousedown',{
            'view': window
            });
$(selector).dispatchEvent(event);
```

There are many similar questions but I wasn't able to come up with a definitive answer...

Comment: Dont you want to use jQuery?

Comment: What about if you will save and trigger boolean flag on event to onclick, and if flag is true, select is opened, else closed?

Comment: He's not trying to trigger an event when the select is opened, he wants to open the select as if the user clicked on it. Anyway, it's not possible.

Comment: It can only be done in Chrome. Your alternative is to use a full js implementation of a combo box providing this behavior.

Comment: if it is not possible, my next question (or curiosity) wuold be: what's the cause that makes the select open in Firefox?